# UWP Page memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, uwp, navigation

At first,I use Frame to navigate my Page,but I found the memory is increase when each navigation.(I have set the NavigationCacheMode to requied).

The managed memory is identical,but non managed memory is increase.

Then I use a Dictionary to save all my pages,Use a ContentPresenter as the page container,but when i set page as the ContentPresenter's Content,the memory is increase also.

```
 Dictionary<Type, Page> navigationPages = new Dictionary<Type, Page>();
    public void Navigate(Type pageType, string param)
    {
        var re = navigationPages.Keys.Contains(pageType);
        if (re == true)
        {
            var page = navigationPages[pageType];
            this.contentPresenter.Content = page;
        }
        else
        {
            var page = Activator.CreateInstance(pageType) as Page;
            navigationPages[pageType] = page;
            this.contentPresenter.Content = page;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share a [MCVE] that can reproduce your issue? I test the Frame to navigate the Page that  has no memory leak issue.

Comment: Here is a demo project.There is a listview in mainPage,when click the items frequently,the memory will increase. GC collect is no effect.       https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhlJbMNnQl72uaB08fU2VRYjj5Pl9A

Comment: I test your project that there is no issue.Could you tell us more detail about your OS version of your Windows and your VS SDK?

Comment: Vs 2017 15.2(26430.15); SDK 15063;OS version:15063; Could you show me your test result?.I use ui automation tool to test the app,click listview's item about 500 times,then the memory is up to 40MB.And GC collect is unuseful.    Thanks.